# Select first row within same value of one column

Tags: mysql

I have these values in a table called message:

```
id       message_id      message
1             1            Hello sir
2             1            Hi dear.
3             2            Send by admin.
4             2            send by helper. 
5             3            created by me. 
6             3            Done by user.
```

What i wnat in result the table is below.

```
id       message_id      message
1             1            Hello sir
3             2            Send by admin. 
5             3            created by me.
```

Any help please.

Comment: use group by message_id

Comment: can you show us what have you done ?

Comment: Please share your query.

Answer (score 1):

you can try as,all you need is just use a distinct clause which selects unique values.

```
SELECT DISTINCT * from meassage;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select M.id, M.message_id, M.message 
from message M
WHERE  M.ID = (SELECT MIN(M1.ID) FROM MESSAGE M1 WHERE M1.MESSAGE_ID = M.MESSAGE_ID) ;
```